# ¿Cómo se puede acceder a un atributo de una clase en c++ desde el .cpp?

Tags: c++, funciones, class, atributos

quería saber si se podría acceder a un atributo de un objeto de la misma clase en la que estás. Es decir, como puedo acceder a estos atributos, definidos en Racional.h:

```
private:
long _numer;     // El numerador
long _denom;     // El denominador
```

Desde Racional.cpp, en el que tengo una función que recibe como parámetro otro objeto de esa misma clase:

```
Racional Suma(const Racional& r) {}
```

Como conclusión, cómo podría acceder desde Racional.cpp a los atributos de "r" sin necesidad de crear getters en la clase.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una funcion independiente tienes que hacerla amiga de la clase:

```cpp
class miclase {

     friend Racional Suma(const Raciomal&  r);

}:
```

Esto último no lo recomiendo, porque rompe el principio del minimo privilegio.

---

Si tu función pertenece a la clase, entonces,  debes implementarla:

```cpp
Racional Racional::Suma(const Racional& racional) {
    
}
```

---

Ahora bien podrias  definir el operador de suma `+=` o`+` de la clase:

```cpp
class miclase {

public:
      Racional& operator+=(const Racional& racional) {      
         
      // operaciones

           return *this,
        }

     Racional& operator+(const Racional& racional,const Racional& racional2) {      
        

           return racional+=racional2;
        }
    }
```

Puedes usarla: `racional+=otroRacional` o `racional=r1+r2`

Con eso tienes algo parecido a lo que quieres:

**NOTA :** En el archivo racional.cpp debes incluir a su respectivo `.h`

```cpp
#include <racional.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, debes saber que en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no existen los [atributos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), te estás refiriendo a miembros de objetos.

Puedes acceder a un miembro de un objeto si éste es público:

```
struct S
{
    int accesible;
private:
    int inaccesible;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << s.accesible;   // Sin problemas.
    std::cout << s.inaccesible; // Error, el miembro es inaccesible.
    return 0;
}
```

La acción de ocultar miembros en el espacio privado de un objeto se conoce como [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Siguiendo los principios del encapsulamiento puedes dar acceso controlado a miembros privados de un objeto mediante funciones de lectura (comunmente conocidas como *geetters* en inglés) o como funciones de escritura (comunmente conocidas como *setters* en inglés):

```
struct S
{
    int dato() const { return inaccesible; }         // Getter de 'inaccesible'
    void establece(int dato) { inaccesible = dato; } // Setter de 'inaccesible'
private:
    int inaccesible;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, desde un .cpp (Entiendo que tu función es un método de la clase) de una clase puedes acceder a los atributos privados de otro objeto, **siempre que sea de la misma clase**.

No tienes que hacer nada especial, puedes acceder a ellos como en una estructura, `nombre_objeto.nombre_atributo`.

Eso si, es recomendable usar `this->` para distinguir los parámetros del objeto que está llamando al método del segundo objeto.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
class posicion {
 private:
    int x=0, y=0, z=0;
 public:
    void copiar(const posicion& a)
};


void posicion::copiar(const posicion& a) {

    this->x = a.x;
    this->y = a.y;
    this->z = a.z;
}
```